# Type Error when trying to extract type from unions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add type definitions to some code that uses message passing over web workers. The dispatched messages have a string type member using which they can be distinguished at runtime.

```
// One type of Message
export interface IOpenFileWMsg {
    type: "OpenFileWMsg"
}

// Another type of message
export interface ICreateFileWMsg {
    type: "CreateFileWMsg"
}

// Disjoint union containing all types of messages
export type IWMsg = IOpenFileWMsg | ICreateFileWMsg

// Helper type to extract a type given its type identifier:
// Eg. ISpecializedWMsg<"OpenFileWMsg"> == OpenFileWMsg
//
// [R1]
export type ISpecializedWMsg<T extends IWMsg["type"]> = Extract<
    IWMsg,
    { type: T }
>

// Function which can handle a message of a specific type
// 
// [R2]
export interface IWMsgHandler<T extends IWMsg["type"]> {
    (msg: ISpecializedWMsg<T>): void
}

// Type of a dictionary of all handlers
export type IWMsgHandlers = {
    [K in IWMsg["type"]]: IWMsgHandler<K>
}

const handlers: IWMsgHandlers = {
    OpenFileWMsg(_event: IOpenFileWMsg) {},
    CreateFileWMsg(_event: ICreateFileWMsg) {},
}

// Handle a general message:
const handleMessage = <T extends IWMsg["type"]>(msg: ISpecializedWMsg<T>) => {
    const type: T = msg.type
    // [R3]
    const handler: IWMsgHandler<T> = handlers[type]
    handler(msg)
}
```

Line [R3] Above gives me following error:

```
Type 'IWMsgHandlers[T]' is not assignable to type 'IWMsgHandler<T>'.
  Type 'IWMsgHandler<"OpenFileWMsg"> | IWMsgHandler<"CreateFileWMsg">' is not assignable to type 'IWMsgHandler<T>'.
    Type 'IWMsgHandler<"OpenFileWMsg">' is not assignable to type 'IWMsgHandler<T>'.
      Types of parameters 'msg' and 'msg' are incompatible.
        Type 'Extract<IOpenFileWMsg, { type: T; }> | Extract<ICreateFileWMsg, { type: T; }>' is not assignable to type 'IOpenFileWMsg'.
          Type 'Extract<ICreateFileWMsg, { type: T; }>' is not assignable to type 'IOpenFileWMsg'.
            Type '{ type: T; } & ICreateFileWMsg' is not assignable to type 'IOpenFileWMsg'.
              Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
                Type 'T & "CreateFileWMsg"' is not assignable to type '"OpenFileWMsg"'.
                  Type '"CreateFileWMsg"' is not assignable to type '"OpenFileWMsg"'. [2322]
```

I would like to understand why this is not working and if this is a known limitation around TypeScript's type system.

---

The best I have been able to achieve so far is:

```
const handler = handlers[type] as IWMsgHandler<any>
```

This upcasting does not result in loss of type safety in this case, but I am still curious why the original approach does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
const handleMessage = <T extends IWMsg["type"]>
```

which when `IWMsg` is expanded becomes simply

```
const handleMessage = <T extends 'OpenFileWMsg' | 'CreateFileWMsg'>
```

you mean that `T` can be either `'OpenFileWMsg'` or `'CreateFileWMsg'`.

But that's not how the compiler interprets it. For the compiler, it literally means `any type that extends either  'OpenFileWMsg' or 'CreateFileWMsg'`

You might think that's no different than just `'OpenFileWMsg' | 'CreateFileWMsg'`, but in javascript, strings are objects and the type system is obliged to model it properly, assuming that string literal type like `'OpenFileWMsg'` indeed can be extended.

By the way, here's how it can be extended:

```
type X = 'OpenFileWMsg' & { foo: string };

let x: X = Object.assign('OpenFileWMsg', { foo: 'bar' });
const type: IWMsg['type'] = x;
```

So, in this implementation

```
const handleMessage = <T extends IWMsg["type"]>(msg: ISpecializedWMsg<T>) => {
    const type: T = msg.type
    // [R3]
    const handler: IWMsgHandler<T> = handlers[type]
    handler(msg)
}
```

there is no guarantee that `handers[type]` is assignable to `IWMsgHandler<T>` because `T` is allowed to be any type that extends `IWMsg["type"]`, not just a single member of a union.

You have to use type assertion:

```
const handleMessage = <T extends IWMsg["type"]>(msg: ISpecializedWMsg<T>) => {
    const type: T = msg.type
    // [R3]
    const handler = handlers[type] as IWMsgHandler<T>;
    handler(msg)
}
```

I remember seeing a feature request or bug on TypeScript github where someone was asking for the ability to express that a type must be precisely one member of a union, but I can't find it now.

**Note** this answer explains the error that you will get with `--strictFunctionTypes` turned off. The error will be different when `--strictFunctionTypes` is on because another incompatibility will be encountered by the compiler, see Titian's answer explaining that.

Comment: Not sure I really agree with you explanation, by your reasoning This should not work, yet it does: `type fns = "fn1" | "fn2"
let test = {
    fn1: (s: number) => {},
    fn2: (s: number) => {}
}
function withTest <T extends fns>(k: T){
    let testFn: (s: number)=> void = test[k];
    testFn(0)
}`

Comment: And actually `'OpenFileWMsg' & { foo: string }` would be usable as a key and would yield the correct result, a derived type is usable where a base type is expected ..

Comment: In the playground, the final line in the error message is `Type '"OpenFileWMsg"' is not assignable to type 'T'.`. I was trying to explain why it is not assignable. Note that this is with `strictFunctionTypes` turned off.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, în non strict the explanation is right. My down vote is locked in, if you edit the answer I can revese it. My bad

Answer (score 2):

Since the compiler can't know the specific type of `T` inside the function, `T` is basically equivalent to both posible values `"OpenFileWMsg" | "CreateFileWMsg"` (and anything derived from them) and if we expand the types on both sides we get:

```
typeof handlers[type] 
    = typeof handlers[IWMsg["type"]]; 
    = IWMsgHandler<"OpenFileWMsg"> | IWMsgHandler<"CreateFileWMsg">
    = ((msg: IOpenFileWMsg) => void) | ((msg: ICreateFileWMsg) => void)

IWMsgHandler<IWMsg["type"]> 
    = IWMsgHandler<"OpenFileWMsg" | "CreateFileWMsg">
    = (msg: IOpenFileWMsg | ICreateFileWMsg) => void
```

So basically you are assigning either a function that can take an `IOpenFileWMsg` or a function that can take `ICreateFileWMsg` to a function that can take either   `IOpenFileWMsg` or `ICreateFileWMsg`

A simplified example as to why this is not safe would be:

```
function takesNumber(n: number){}
function takesSting(s: string){}

let takesEither : (sn: number| string)=> void = takesNumber; // Invalid
takesEither("") // This would be a runtime error
```