# Surprising type error when trying to update a tagged union

Tags: typescript

I would expect the code below to work just fine, but line 7 errors with the message `Type '"one"' is not assignable to type '"two"'.`:

```
type One = { type: 'one', value: number }
type Two = { type: 'two', value: number }

type OneOrTwo = One | Two

function handleOneOrTwo(oneOrTwo: OneOrTwo): OneOrTwo {
  const nextOneOrTwo: OneOrTwo = {
    type: oneOrTwo.type,
    value: oneOrTwo.value + 1,
  }
  return nextOneOrTwo
}
```

This is rather surprising. Especially given that when I update the function to use a switch statement (with identical functionality), it works:

```
type One = { type: 'one', value: number }
type Two = { type: 'two', value: number }

type OneOrTwo = One | Two

function handleOneOrTwo(oneOrTwo: OneOrTwo): OneOrTwo {
  const nextOneOrTwo = {
    value: oneOrTwo.value + 1,
  }

  switch (oneOrTwo.type) {
    case 'one':
      return { ...nextOneOrTwo, type: oneOrTwo.type }
    case 'two':
      return { ...nextOneOrTwo, type: oneOrTwo.type }
    default:
      throw unreachable(oneOrTwo)
  }
}

function unreachable(value: never) {
  return new Error(value)
}
```

Even casting type doesn't work (`type: oneOrTwo.type as 'one' | 'two'`).

I've read the answers to [Type Error when trying to extract type from unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227356/type-error-when-trying-to-extract-type-from-unions) but I'm still unsure as to why this error happens & how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because when you access the `type` of the union it is `one | two`. But when you are assigning the object literal the way the check works is if the object literal matches at least one member of the union then the assignment is valid.

So let see. The type of the object literal is `{ type : 'one' | 'two' value: number }`.

Is the object literal type compatible with `One` ? No, `type` is `'one' | 'two'` in the object literal, but it is `'one'` in `One`

Is the object literal type compatible with `Two` ? No, `type` is `'one' | 'two'` in the object literal, but it is `'two'` in `Two`

So you end up with an object  literal that is assignable to neither member of the union.

A non type assertion option is to use a spread expression, which will preserve the original union type:

```
function handleOneOrTwo(oneOrTwo: OneOrTwo): OneOrTwo {
  const nextOneOrTwo: OneOrTwo = {
     ...oneOrTwo,
    value: oneOrTwo.value + 1,
  }
  return nextOneOrTwo
}
```

Or to use a type assertion:

```
function handleOneOrTwo(oneOrTwo: OneOrTwo): OneOrTwo {
   const nextOneOrTwo: OneOrTwo = {
     type: oneOrTwo.type,
     value: oneOrTwo.value + 1,
   } as OneOrTwo
   return nextOneOrTwo
}
```

Comment: Looks like most of the typescript stuff can be solved with type assertions. +1 for the spread approach

Comment: @MuratKaragöz type assertions are the hammer to make the shapes of types fit. Like a toddler trying to force a square in a circle. Sometimes that kind of force is needed but it is best avoided :)

Comment: [Relevant issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052)... any concrete value of type `OneOrTwo` should also be of type `{ type : 'one' | 'two' value: number }` and vice versa, so they should be mutually assignable types.  But the compiler doesn't put in the effort to verify that because it is really not worth the performance hit... if you want `{ type : 'one' | 'two' value: number }` then use that type.  Tagged unions are meant to differ in their non-tag properties; if they don't then there's not much point to them.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks again Titian (you also answered my last TS question )